# Import Objective-C pod as a dependency into Swift pod

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, podspec

- Both of them are Cocoapods private pods
- I need to use them as Development Pods

Answer (score 0):

**.podspec:**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name = 'MyMainPod'
  spec.dependency 'MyObjCSubPod'
  ...
end
```

**Podfile:**

```
pod 'MyMainPod', :path => 'private-pods/my-main-pod/'
pod 'MyObjCSubPod', :path => 'private-pods/my-main-pod/my-objc-subpod'
```

**SomeFile.swift:**

```
import MyObjCSubPod
```

No additional bridging headers required.

Comment: but what if i want Import Swift pod as a dependency into Objective-C pod? whats the procedure and steps kindly help me out